# Is it possible to use and image in a CDN as the OG image in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cdn, next.js13

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const { url } = await getOgImage();
  const ogImageUrl = new URL(`https:${url}`);

  const metadata = metadataConfig

  return {
    ...metadata,
    openGraph: {
      images: ogImageUrl,
    },
    icons: {
      icon: '/favicon/favicon.ico',
    },
    applicationName: '...',
  };
}
```

The problem is Next prefixes the URL with the domain of the app. so `cdn.images.com/image` becomes `https://someHost.com/cdn.images.com/image`

Answer (score 0):

Redesign your openGraph property and add metadataBase property like the below example:

```
metadataBase: new URL(ogImageUrl.origin),
openGraph: {
  type: "website",
  url: ogImageUrl.origin,
  title: "My Website",
  description: "My Website Description",
  siteName: "My Website",
  images: [
    {
      url: ogImageUrl,
    },
  ],
},
```

`metadata.metadataBase` is not set for resolving social open graph or twitter images, using `http://localhost:3000` || "https://someHost.com/".